# Remote validation in ASP.NET Core 2.1 value not being passed to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am attempting to use remote validation using the following documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.1#remote-validation

My method looks like the following:

```
[AcceptVerbs("Get", "Post")]
public IActionResult UniqueName(string name) //name comes in as null
{
    if (_categoryRepository.DoesCategoryNameExist(name))
        return Json($"{name} already exists.");

    return Json(true); //valid
}
```

And the validation attribute is used like so:

```
public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required and must not be empty.")]
    [StringLength(200, ErrorMessage = "Name should not exceed 200 characters.")]
    [Remote(action: "UniqueName", controller: "Category")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

View looks as follows:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input asp-for="Category.Name" class="form-control frmInput" id="categoryName" placeholder="Name">
    <span asp-validation-for="Category.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

The remote validation is triggered, however the name parameter in the UniqueName method comes in as null.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You need to show the view code for your `Name` property

Comment: I've updated my post.

Comment: Your not posting back a value for `Name` - your posting it back for `Catagory.Name`

Comment: As a side note, do not use data models in your view (and a `[Remote]` attribute is not applicable on a data model anyway)